# How do I sort an ArrayList by date in string format

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, arraylist

I'm currently programming a small notes app and saving everything as strings in the sharedPrefs. I would now like to sort the overview of the note entries so that the most recent entries are always displayed at the top.

The problem is that when I sort on the note body, the sorting works, but not by date. The date is stored in the form dd.mm.yyyy in the sharedPrefs as a string. How can I realize that?

Here is the method that loads all the data from the sharedPref.

```
public static ArrayList<Note> loadAll(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> noteIds = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(ID_KEY, null);

        if (noteIds != null) {
            for (String noteId : noteIds) {
                notes.add(load(context, noteId));
            }
        }
       Collections.sort(notes, new Comparator<Note>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Note o1, Note o2) {
// sorting by body-string works fine yeah
                return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
            }
        });
        return notes;
    }
```

Here i have two screenshots. sorting by body and sorting by date

[image: Sorting by body with simple letter works]

[image: The sorting by date doesn't work]

Comment: A "hacky" way is to put years, then months then days. yyyymmdd no one would ever put it any other way in string if they wanted to sort the string.

Comment: `List<Note> sorted = notes.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Note::getDate)).toList();` will do it

Comment: *A "hacky" way is to put years ...* Or looking at it differently, to use a proper ISO date format ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: First of all you don’t put dates as strings in your `Note` objects. You put `LocalDate`objects there for dates. It’s more correct as modelling, and will make your task much easier, almost trivial. Second you search before posting a question here. While the solution didn’t come up in my first search hit, it wasn’t hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

You may convert the `String` dates to bona fide `LocalDate` and then sort:

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
notes.sort(
  (String s1, String s2) -> LocalDate.parse(s1, f).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(s2, f)));
```

But the best general approach would be to maintain your dates as `LocalDate`s in the application, rather than storing as text.

Comment: thanks for your Answer. 

Thanks to your help, I have now implemented this here.
notes.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> LocalDate.parse(o.getDate(), f)));
   
Unfortunately, the latest date is now at the bottom.

Comment: Yes you are right the best way is dates to save as dateTime, but when i change the sharedPref and rollout the app in the new version, all users lost there data because there is no way to handle updates of such models. yes that's bad but I got the code as a gift and I'm only about to migrate the model to a DB soon

Comment: *Unfortunately, the latest date is now at the bottom* then you can do `List<Note> sorted = notes.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Note::getDate).reversed()).toList();`

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77977248/642706) is correct. As wisely advised there, you should represent a date in your class as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Here is an example class written as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Note ( LocalDate date , String text ) {}
```

Sample data.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;  // Better to pass your specific desired/expected time zone (`ZoneId`). 
List < Note > notes = 
    new ArrayList<>( 
        List.of(
            new Note ( today , "today again" ) ,
            new Note ( today , "today" ) ,
            new Note ( today.plusDays( 1 ) , "tomorrow" ) ,
            new Note ( today.minusDays( 1 ) , "yesterday" )
        )
    ) ;
```

Sort. No need for `Collections.sort` class. [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) has its own [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method as of Java 8+.

```
notes.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing( Note :: date )      // Two-level sort. First sort by date member field.
        .thenComparing( Note :: text )  // Then sort by text member field.
) ;
```

If you want to maintain that sorted order all along, and eliminate any duplicates, use a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html)/`SortedSet` implementation such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

```
NavigableSet < Note > notes = 
    new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator
           .comparing( Note :: date )
           .thenComparing( Note :: text )
    ) ;
```

No need to call `sort`. As you add elements, they automatically sort.

---

By the way, in Java 21+ we can use [`SequencedCollection`](https://SequencedCollection) as the more general interface rather than `List` or  `NavigableSet`. See [*Java JEP 431*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```
SequencedCollection < Note > notes = 
    new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator
           .comparing( Note :: date )
           .thenComparing( Note :: text )
    ) ;
```